# AWS CLI S3, error when downloading - fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-403

I need to run two aws s3 cli commands:

1. `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/ --recursive`
2. `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/ec2_keypair.pem ec2_keypair.pem`

And:

- on my laptop they both work well (list correctly the files on the bucket and download correctly the file contained in the ENV variable)
- on a Linux VM the 1st command works well and lists correctly the files, while the 2nd one produces the error `fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

The AWS credentials used on my laptop and on the Linux VM - aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key and default.region - are the same.

How can I solve or at least debug this?
I've tried many different solutions but nothing seems to work.

Update: here's the last part of the output when running with --debug option:

```
2022-06-13 08:49:26,151 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:

2022-06-13 08:49:26,155 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.HeadObject: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7fe5ad1fa8d0>
2022-06-13 08:49:26,155 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - No retry needed.
2022-06-13 08:49:26,155 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.HeadObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7fe5ad1fa950>>
2022-06-13 08:49:26,155 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.HeadObject: calling handler <function enhance_error_msg at 0x7fe5ae0b3bd0>
2022-06-13 08:49:26,156 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.s3.results - DEBUG - Exception caught during command execution: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/circleci/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/s3handler.py", line 173, in call
    for fileinfo in fileinfos:
  File "/opt/circleci/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/fileinfobuilder.py", line 31, in call
    for file_base in files:
  File "/opt/circleci/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/filegenerator.py", line 142, in call
    for src_path, extra_information in file_iterator:
  File "/opt/circleci/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/filegenerator.py", line 318, in list_objects
    yield self._list_single_object(s3_path)
  File "/opt/circleci/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/filegenerator.py", line 355, in _list_single_object
    response = self._client.head_object(**params)
  File "/opt/circleci/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/circleci/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
2022-06-13 08:49:26,157 - Thread-1 - awscli.customizations.s3.results - DEBUG - Shutdown request received in result processing thread, shutting down result thread.
```

Comment: I'd run something like ` aws s3 ls --debug 2>&1 | grep Credential=` and make sure you're using the same credentials on both instances.

Comment: hi, thank you for you answer. I confirm the credentials are the same, as well as the user if I exec the command 'aws iam list-roles' over the 2 sistems

Comment: Can you post the output for `aws s3 cp --debug s3://my-bucket/ec2_keypair.pem ec2_keypair.pem` on both machines?

Comment: run `aws sts get-caller-identity` and `aws configure list` to confirm that the AWSCLI is using the correct IAM Role/User you are expecting.

Comment: hi @tino1b2be:
1) the outputs of aws sts get-caller-identity in my laptop and the linux vm are the same (same UserId, same Account, same Arn)
2) also the outputs of aws configure list are the same

Comment: @Uberhumus I just included the log in the original question

Comment: I'm guessing that there's a mismatch between the Python version, and the AWS CLI version on the VM, specifically in that `venv/virtualenv` you're using.
Python 2.7 is EOL over a year now. If you can, remove the AWS CLI, make sure that the VM has Python 3, and reinstall the AWS CLI via `pip` after you have made sure that version of pip works with Python3.

Comment: it turned out to be a cross-region issue... thanks everyone!

Comment: @user1403546 Hi, how did you solve it? I am encountering a similar issue.